# shutdown script ubuntu 16.04 systemd

Tags: scripts, shutdown, startup

im fight 2 days now and dont get closer to reason. May someone out there knows...

my goal, having a shutdown script that stops some sevices of my own and something more any time the system reboot or shutdown.

so i simple up my test scrip and i did the following:

Creating a script: /etc/rc.shutdown
Content:

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
    #
    # rc.shutdown
    #
    #
    # just for test
    echo "last shutdown or reboot:" > /var/log/rc.shutdown.info
    echo `date` >> /var/log/rc.shutdown.info
    sleep 10
    exit 0

Creating the file /etc/rc.startup  
Content:

#!/bin/sh
#
# rc.startup
#
#
# just for test
echo "last boot:" > /var/log/rc.startup.info
echo `date` >> /var/log/rc.startup.info
sleep 5
exit 0
```

Creating the service file /etc/systemd/system/rc.shutdown.service
Content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown_Reboot Script /etc/rc.shutdown
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target local-fs.target network-online.target network.target
Wants=network-online.target local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash /etc/rc.startup
ExecStop=/bin/bash /etc/rc.shutdown
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardOutput=syslog+console
StandardError=syslog+console

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target
```

Making the rc.startup and rc.shutdown executable with `chmod a+x ..`

Enabled the service with `systemctl enable rc.shutdown`

But whatever i do and try, the script wont start at shutdown... wtf..? what i'm doing wrong?

If somebody aks why i add all that dependencies with before, because i wanted it to get running as one of the first things the system runs to take sure all needed services for "doing whatever have to be done" is running.

Comment: Just a wild guess: `network-online.target` is probably reached before your service is going to be executed, and since it then cannot be executed before `network-online.target`, it's not executed at all.

Comment: ok maybe... so i will remove it, but btw.. i also only had `poweroff.target halt.target` and `reboot.target` and it was not working too. The scripts run if i start it manually, and the service is starting the ExecStart/ExecStop if i do `systemctl stop` or `systemctl start`. But its not working at poweroff/reboot. What i forget to say in addition is, that i didnt place the script in /lib/systemd/system-shutdown because the're executed in parallel - and, i dont accept that it did not work with systemd as a service :-)

Comment: i only experimented with all that `before` statements because i tought its not running because something needed is already stopped. but you can correct me everytime please...

Comment: i too have to correct my first posting... i wrongly place /etc/rc.startup  in the code of /etc/rc.shutdown. For sure.. that are two separate files. I'm sorry.

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39226/285436) at U&L could be helpful.

Comment: Sorry no, danzel that doesn't help and is nothing new for me.